# Magit - "user" in Branch / Create from Pull Request

Tags: magit

I've been using Magit for a long time, but finally read the manual, and started playing in the deep water. Not sure how to fix what I did...

I tried `b Y` (Branch / Create from pull request). It asked me for a GitHub id, which seemed strange, but OK, so I entered my email address. Nothing happened, so I tried the command again and it warns me about creating a GitHub API Token.
Presumably I put in the wrong thing for the username. How do I undo this, and how is this command supposed to be used?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably just fine, and don't need to worry much about "undoing" anything. Forgive me if some or all of this is review, but here's what I think is happening for you:

A "pull request" isn't an idea within `git` itself; it's idiomatic to Github in particular (though several other VC hosting services, like Bitbucket and GitLab, have adopted the idea). What `magit` is trying to help you do is to make a local branch out of someone else's pull request *against your remote on github*. To do this, it will need to make API requests against github, for which it will want a github API token. You can make one for yourself in your github account -- the setting for it is inside your account management view. Or, you can just pretend nothing ever happened and go back to just using Magit happily.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  That was the answer.  I found it now, too, at https://magit.vc/manual/ghub/Interactively-Creating-and-Storing-a-Token.html#Interactively-Creating-and-Storing-a-Token